# How to install the beta version of @nuxtjs/auth?

Tags: nuxt.js

When I run `npm view @nuxtjs/auth dist-tags`, I get `{ latest: '4.9.1' }`, the development version is not listed. How are we supposed to install it ?

```
$ npm install @nuxtjs/auth@beta
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @nuxtjs/auth@beta.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2020-05-28T23_02_05_605Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The beta version is in another package:

```
npm i @nuxtjs/auth-next
```